# Query postgresql for max and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want get data in table by group and max.

example:

| code | date | customercode | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CD01 | 2022-03-01 | 001 | OK |
| CD02 | 2022-03-02 | 001 | OK |
| CD03 | 2022-03-03 | 001 | OK |
| CD04 | 2022-03-01 | 002 | OK |
| CD05 | 2022-03-02 | 002 | OK |
| CD06 | 2022-03-03 | 002 | OK |

result:

| code | date | customercode | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CD03 | 2022-03-03 | 001 | OK |
| CD06 | 2022-03-03 | 002 | OK |

How to query with PostgreSQL?

Comment: Could you post your data sample and desired output as text?

Comment: Asked [hundreds of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+postgresql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on(customercode) *
from table_name
order by customercode, date desc;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3da402c2227bc02e0568522ba85769f7)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then you are asking on how to get the max date

```
Select * FROM yourtable WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM yourtable) GROUP BY 'your desire columns' order by 'your desire columns'
```